# How to Get Read-Write Access to Big Query from Inside a Docker Container?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

###### Context

I am running a cron job which

- Pulls some data from big query (using SQL Alchemy ORM interface)
- Does some feature engineering and machine learning inference
- Inserts the results into another big query schema (again, using SQL alchemy)

The simple diagram describes what's happening.

[image]

Now, I have authenticated my instance (Ubuntu 22.04)  to access the BQ by logging into google, which is a browser based authentication. Basically, I got a file `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` looking like

```json
{
  "account": "",
  "client_id": "70-6ur.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "d-FLy",
  "quota_project_id": "clustering-production",
  "refresh_token": "1//0wF-LY",
  "type": "authorized_user",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

###### Question

How to containerise the job using docker so that I can run it on any host without manual set up of the python dependencies? Basically, I know docker, but not sure how to enable the container to access the big query. Should I put my original `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` in the corresponding directory inside the container so that it can authorise the BQ access?

Comment: What do you mean by run on any host? Host on Google Cloud? or host elsewhere?

Comment: Can be on google cloud, or elsewhere. Basically, I want to make a container that can run this job on any host that has docker installed. So how to authenticate BQ access from the docker container. That is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be authenticated on Google Cloud you must have a Google Cloud identity.

This identity is natively provided on Google Cloud thanks to the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) that runs on all Google Cloud Services.
The Google Cloud Client library will automatically discover that you run on Google Cloud and use the metadata server for the identity

If you are not on Azure or AWS, it's pretty easy to use a similar mechanism combine with [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) (Could work also on other environment, but need to be validated)
You have to create an environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that contains the path to this file. You can pass the env var and mount the path on your container when you run it. *You can take inspiration from [one of my articles](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da)*

Finally, you can use a service account key file to transport this identity. You MUST NOT include this file in the container. The container is not a secured box and anyone can have access to the data inside it.
It's better have the file on the runtime environment and do the same as Workload Identity Federation

This mechanism (search for metadata server, search for a specific env var,...) implemented in all the client libraries of Google Cloud is named [ADC (Application Default Credetial)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)

---

That being said, did you consider using [BigQUery remote functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/remote-functions)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. So, according to your medium article (very informative and useful), should the ```GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS``` env variable point to the file looking exactly like the sample I shared above?

Comment: Further, can the ```GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS``` be a relative path from the working directory? Or it necessarily has to be the absolute path?

Comment: It can be relative, but it's safer to set it absolute. You have a better control on the execution environment